# 2D transient heat equation resolution

Tags: differential-equations, modeling, heat-equation

I'm writing a code to get the analytical solution mentioned in Sun et al., 2013. I will copy here the passages needed to solve the equation.
The 2D transient heat equation is:
[image]

First of all, I set the geometry and the thermal properties:

```
W = 1.2; 
Subscript[L, 1] = 0.5;
Subscript[L, 2] = 5; 
{x1, y1} = {0.25, 0.05};
{x2, y2} = {0.25, 0.75};
Subscript[d, pipe] = 0.03;
Subscript[\[Rho], CLS] = 2400; 
Subscript[Cp, CLS] = 880; 
Subscript[k, CLS] = 1.4;
Subscript[\[Rho], soil] = 1850;
Subscript[Cp, soil] = 1500;
Subscript[k, soil] = 2.2;
tend = 1000;
```

The subscript i in the equation (1) stands for the two regions of the domain. The domain represents the section of a diaphragm panel and the adiacent soil: on the left there is a diaphragm wall with 2 heat exchangers modelled as point heat sources and on the right there is the soil.

```
plane = RegionUnion[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {Subscript[L, 1], W}], 
   Rectangle[{Subscript[L, 1], 0}, {Subscript[L, 2], W}]];
Graphics[{Gray, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {Subscript[L, 1], W}], Brown, 
  Rectangle[{Subscript[L, 1], 0}, {Subscript[L, 2], W}]}]

section = 
  RegionDifference[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {Subscript[L, 2], W}], 
   ImplicitRegion[(x - x1)^2 + (y - y1)^2 < (Subscript[d, pipe]/
         2)^2 || (x - x2)^2 + (y - y2)^2 < (Subscript[d, pipe]/
         2)^2, {x, y}]];
RegionPlot[section, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

To set the point heat sources:

```
q0 = 10; (*W/m*)
Subscript[Q, 0] = 
  q0*(DiracDelta[x - x1]*DiracDelta[y - y1] + 
     DiracDelta[x - x1]*DiracDelta[y - y2]*DiracDelta[x - x2]*
      DiracDelta[y - y1] + DiracDelta[x - x2]*DiracDelta[y - y2]);
```

I divided the governing equation into 2 similar ones to model the diaphragm and the soil separately. The equation for the diaphragm can be now obtained as follows:

```
heqn1 = Subscript[k, 
    CLS]*(D[Subscript[T, D][x, y, t], x, x] + 
      D[Subscript[T, D][x, y, t], y, y]) + Subscript[Q, 0] == 
  Subscript[\[Rho], CLS]*Subscript[Cp, CLS]*
   D[Subscript[T, D][x, y, t], t]
heqn1 = heqn1 /. {DiracDelta[x_] :> \[Delta][x]}
```

At this point, IC, BC and CC, mentioned in the paper:
[image]

that I wrote in the following form:

```
Subscript[T, 0] = 25;
inD = Subscript[T, D][x, y, 0] == Subscript[T, 0]
BC1D = -Subscript[k, CLS]*D[Subscript[T, D][x, y, t], x] + 
    h*(Subscript[T, D][x, y, t] - f) == 0 /. x -> 0 
BC3D = -Subscript[k, CLS]*D[Subscript[T, D][x, y, t], y] == 0 /. 
  y -> 0
BC4D = Subscript[k, CLS]*D[Subscript[T, D][x, y, t], y] == 0 /. y -> W
```

I thought I could neglect the point heat source when dealing with the soil side, hence the governing equation I wrote is:

```
heqn2 = Subscript[k, 
   soil]*(D[Subscript[T, S][x, y, t], x, x] + 
     D[Subscript[T, S][x, y, t], y, y]) == 
  Subscript[\[Rho], soil]*Subscript[Cp, soil]*
   D[Subscript[T, S][x, y, t], t]
```

with IC and BC:

```
Subscript[T, 0] = 25;
inS = Subscript[T, S][x, y, 0] == Subscript[T, 0]
BC2S = Subscript[T, S][x, y, t] == Subscript[T, 0] /. 
  x -> Subscript[L, 2] /. t -> 0
BC3S = -Subscript[k, soil]*D[Subscript[T, S][x, y, t], y] == 0 /. 
  y -> 0
BC4S = Subscript[k, soil]*D[Subscript[T, S][x, y, t], y] == 0 /. 
  y -> W
```

and finally the continuity conditions on the interface:

```
CC1 = Subscript[T, D][x, y, 0] == Subscript[T, S][x, y, 0] /. 
  x -> Subscript[L, 1]
CC2 = Subscript[k, CLS]*D[Subscript[T, D][x, y, 0], x] == 
   Subscript[k, soil]*D[Subscript[T, S][x, y, 0], x] /. 
  x -> Subscript[L, 1]
```

The resolution must be analytical, in fact I use DSolve:

```
solfin = NDSolve[{heqn1, inD, BC1D, BC3D, BC4D, heqn2, inS, BC2S, 
   BC3S, BC4S, CC1, CC2}, Subscript[T, D][x, y, t], 
  Subscript[T, S][x, y, t], {x, 0, Subscript[L, 2]}, {y, 0, W}, {t, 0,
    tend}]
```

But it won't solve it. It says "DSolve::litarg: To avoid possible ambiguity, the arguments of the dependent variable in Subscript[T, D][x,y,t] should literally match the independent variables."
I have no idea if the interface conditions work properly and there are also initial conditions, maybe this could be a problem.

I hope someone can help me! Thank you so much